# Spawning with a generic typecast in UE4/UE5 c++

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

**Background**

I'm trying to refactor some of my code for a rts that i'm building in my spare time. As it stands now, i have a hardcoded function for each and every building type. What i would like to have is one generic function to which i can just pass a class to.

**Question**

In ue/c++, can i spawn a generic class, and how do i do that?
(*given that the class can be spawned when type-casted*)
(*All objects are subclasses of a base 'building class': 'ABuilding'*)

I've tried different variations of this snippet, but can't seem to get it working.

```
void AGenericClass::GenericConstructionOrder(UClass* GenericBuildingClass, FVector SpawnPoint, FRotator SpawnRotation)
{
    const auto Controller = Cast<ARTSPlayerController>(GetOwningPlayerController());

    FActorSpawnParameters SpawnInfo;
    SpawnInfo.SpawnCollisionHandlingOverride = ESpawnActorCollisionHandlingMethod::AlwaysSpawn;
    auto BuildingToProspect = GetWorld()->SpawnActor(GenericBuildingClass->StaticClass(), SpawnPoint, SpawnRotation, SpawnInfo);

    GetOwningPlayerController()->SetOwner(BuildingToProspect);
    BuildingToProspect->SetupPlayerInputComponent(Controller->InputComponent);
}
```

**Solution**

I just had to remove the '->StaticClass()' call

Thanks to [George](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6564148/george)

```
void AGenericClass::GenericConstructionOrder(UClass* GenericBuildingClass, FVector SpawnPoint, FRotator SpawnRotation)
{
    const auto Controller = Cast<ARTSPlayerController>(GetOwningPlayerController());

    FActorSpawnParameters SpawnInfo;
    SpawnInfo.SpawnCollisionHandlingOverride = ESpawnActorCollisionHandlingMethod::AlwaysSpawn;
    auto BuildingToProspect = GetWorld()->SpawnActor(GenericBuildingClass, SpawnPoint, SpawnRotation, SpawnInfo);

    GetOwningPlayerController()->SetOwner(BuildingToProspect);
    BuildingToProspect->SetupPlayerInputComponent(Controller->InputComponent);
}
```

Comment: I tried to implement a function template, can't remember why it didn't work. Maybe it has something to do with the scope of ue. I will try again and return with my result

Comment: This is already close to what I think you're trying to do. But `GetWorld()->SpawnActor(GenericBuildingClass->StaticClass()` should just be `GetWorld()->SpawnActor(GenericBuildingClass`. If that's still not working can you detail exactly what problems you're having (exact compile errors etc...)

Comment: @George that actually solved it. Thank you so much.